# Что мне может дать знание языка Perl и чем он хорош?

Tags: perl

Думаю начать изучать язык Perl. Чем то он мне понравился. Но думаю - стоит или нет? Поэтому решил спросить у знающих людей. В чем хорош язык Perl и что мне может дать его знание?

Comment: А что ты хочешь от него получить? Знание может дать например денег... а может и ничего не дать. Тут не угадать. Если хотите простой язык, чтобы деньги зарабатывать - тогда PHP, на нём куча сайтов сделана.

Comment: Поправлю: сайты свёрстаны на html, а на рнр - написаны движки :)

Comment: в качестве оффтопа 
http://images.yandex.ru/yandsearch?rpt=simage&img_url=assets.doloreslabs.com%2Fimages%2FLangSent.png&ed=1&text=Perl%20happy&p=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да много чего. Во-первых, и самое главное, встряхнёт мозг, perl очень многогранен и его идеология tmtowtdi заставляет мозг шевелиться очень активно. Во-вторых, ничем не хуже последователей, а местами даже круче. В-третьих, хорошие Perl-кодеры ценятся очень хорошо. Если пхп-кодеров сейчас много, то хорошего Perl-программиста днём с огнём не сыскать.

Сам по себе Perl ни в чём не проигрывает, не слушайте про "сложность синтаксиса", "невозможно читать", "мусорный код", это всё не так. На любом языке можно писать мусор, плюс Perl-а в том, что он снисходительно позволяет этому мусору работать как обычно.

По скорости, в общем зачёте, единственный конкурент это python. По технологиям Perl никогда не отставал, CPAN содержит миллион всевозможных модулей на все случаи жизни. Сейчас Perl переживает второе рождение в качестве веб-языка, очень активно развиваются действительно современные веб-фреймворки, посмотрите на [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us) и [Dancer](http://perldancer.org/), например, и вам уже никогда не захочется видеть пхп, а местами и питон, притом ничуть не сложнее RoR, но шустрее и мощнее.

Кроме того, одно из основных применений Perl - это системные задачи, ["однострочники"](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/perl-one-liners-explained-part-one/) на сегодня мощнейшее средство, которого нет у других языков (на таком уровне).

Answer (score 1):

Изучение дополнительного языка может дать:

- дополнительный пункт в резюме при трудоустройстве, который вы предъявите работодателю,
- расширение инструментария, которым вы сможете решать рабочие задачи,
- расширение кругозора, за счет ознакомления со специфические приемами языка,

Собственно Perl - скриптовый язык, в основном применяемый для автоматизации задач системного администрирования. Если в будущем вы планируете как-либо работать в этой области, то изучение языка впрок не повредит, а если не планируете, то лучше изучить что-либо более насущно полезное.

Answer (score 1):

- Возможность писать программы на нем. Как правило, на perl пишут веб приложения и скрипты для автоматизации практически чего угодно. Хотя в теории можно писать и игры под винду, но для этого обычно используют C++.
- Устроиться на работу, где требуются знания Perl. Новые вакансии регулярно появляются на hh.ru.
- Стать более опытным программистом и вообще прокачать мозги